# How to break the loop after scanning the main directory for virus python

Tags: python, linux, loops

I have a linux server where people drop folders containing certain files. I have to scan the folder for virus and move it to another location. I am able to scan the folder, but it also scans the sub folders and files, so I get many email. Is there a way to break the scan when the first scan is done?

```py
for dirs,subdirs,files in os.walk(path):
    for direct in subdirs:
     dirss=(os.path.join(dirs,direct))
     with os.scandir(dirss) as listOfEntries:
        for entry in listOfEntries:
           age = time.time() - entry.stat().st_mtime
           if age > 60:
               data=os.path.join(dirss,entry)
               value= subprocess.run(['clamscan', '-r',data],capture_output=True,text=True)
               p1 = value.stdout
               p1 = p1.split("\n")
               for we in p1:
                if 'Infected' in we:
                 new = we.split(":")
                 new[1] =new[1].strip()
                 if new[1] == "0":
 # print all entries that are filer
                  if entry.is_dir():
```

Comment: you can break your for loop when you find an infected file with `break`, can't you? or maybe I misunderstood the problem

Comment: lets say ther is folder called A and inside that ther is B folder and then inside B ther is a file. so while scanning if folder A is infected and  i want it to break. but here it again goes into the folder B and scan . and then again it scans that file also.

Comment: what about making it a function and just return when you find the first infected file?